# MS Access Filter Child Table by Record Chose on Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, parent-child

I'm trying to create a simple 2 table database - table 1 holds ClientInfo and table 2 has ClientVisits - Relationship is on ClientInfo.ID->ClientVisits.ClientID. Then I have a form created thus for viewing the ClientInfo plus a child(sub?)table which SHOULD show all the records from ClientVisits where my Form ClientID = ClientVisits.ClientID.

[Here is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKCr.jpg)

[Here is the child table with fields shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR8KH.jpg)

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwl2R.jpg)

So I already have one record in ClientVisits for the currently chosen ClientID form record. But it doesn't show in my Table.ClientVisits. Other than the relationship I don't have any other link between the ClientID and the ClientVisits.ClientID field.

If I need to post further info please let me know, trying to describe this as well as I can - sorry if it's not making sense. Thanks.

Comment: You have to link both tables in the form too. Have you done it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to link both tables in your form.

In my example, main data of my form is a table called **CLIENTES**, where it shows all the information about a cliente. It would be exactly the same as your table **ClientDetails**. In this table, primary key is a field called **DNI** (it would be the equivalent of your ID field)

I got a second table called **CONSULTAS MÉDICAS**. This table is just a list of how many times this client comes to see us. It would be the same as your secondary table CLIENT VISITS. In this table, I got a field called **PACIENTE**, linked to my table **CLIENTES**. Let me show you.

[image]

Ok, now my form is done based on the data of my table **CLIENTES**, but I got a subform control, where I have linked the table **CONSULTAS MÉDICAS**

[image]

To make this work is pretty easy. Not filters or queries. Just linked child and master fields. To do this, you have to select properties of your subform control, and **then go to DATA TAB**

[image]

Just choose as main field your **ID field from table CLIENT DETAILS** and link it to child field **CLIENT ID from table CLIENT VISITS**

That should work for you.

Comment: Wow that's awesome, thankyou. Works a treat and I can keep progressing. If you are able could I see a copy of an empty version of your database as it may give me some other ideas for clever formatting and the like. I'm also happy to share my structure in case it might benefit you.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share that info with you, but if you get stuck again, just come back to SO and post a question. Also, if this answer helped, please, mark it as correct, so the question will be closed.

Comment: No problems, I've made steady progress since this and have an unrelated question about VBA so I'll post a new thread about that. thankyou again for your help.

Edit: where is the link/button to mark the answer as correct? I don't see one...

Comment: Every time you post a new thread, somebody will try to help for sure :)  About the link/button to mark the answer as correct, it is right down below the counter, at the start of my answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You should see it green once is marked.